# android studio hiding away after creating flutter project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

`Android Studio` hiding after creating project in `Flutter`. and making a background noise probably running on background but could not find the `IDE` to interact with? very annoying, has installed and reinstalled few times no luck still the same. Just couple of days ago was working fine. any one can help or facing same issue please update.

[Youtube video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INS8eZy_TOA&t=18s)

Comment: Looks like its not an IDE issue, your'e also creating a `flutter` project, have you checked the `flutter doctor` and see if there's any error in it?

Comment: unfortunately still the same not sure how to fix this 
C:\
λ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2130], locale en-GB)[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
• No issues found!